# Finding a controversy parameter from aggregated votes

Tags: google-sheets

I made a survey where users could vote on a subject. They were allowed to either `yay` it (+1) , `nay` it (–1) or `don't care` (0).

I only have the aggregate results in Google Sheets like

```
            yay   nay   dontcare
Option A:    32    14     23
Option B:    12    37     20
Option C:    40    17     12
Option D:    64     3      2
```

The number of votes are always the same on every option.

Now I need to find out how controversial the answers are. I thought about STDEVP, but I do not have a list of cells, just the aggregates.

How do I find the standard deviation here with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you ignore don't care's you can just take the prevalence of yay's and use sd=sqrt(p(1-p))

so if yay's are in column B, nays in C you use

```
=SQRT(B2/SUM(B2:C2) * (C2/SUM(B2:C2)))
```

Note that this is the standard deviation for a population.

---

If you want to include them you can use calculate the mean in E2 with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:D2, {1, -1, 0}) / SUM(B2:D2)
```

Then you can calculate variance like this in F2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ArrayFormula({1, -1, 0}-E2)^2, B2:D2) / (SUM(B2:D2)-1)
```

which is just taking every 1, -1, or 0 reduces by the mean, squares this deviation it and takes the average -1 degree of freedom (for the sample, leave the -1 out if you assume you have the population).

The Standard deviation is

```
=SQRT(F2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, looks like there are a couple of functions I didn't know about. But `ArrayFormula({1, -1, 0}-E2)^2` returns a single number, and not a list. I'll try to fix it somehow.

Comment: It does, that's strange but but within the encapsulating formula it seems to work as the result is correct. If this bothers you though you can use `=ArrayFormula(POW({1, -1, 0}-E2, 2))`

Comment: Thanks again! It did not work for me within the formula - maybe because of my locale settings (german) where I need to replace comma with semicolon. I got it working with `SUMPRODUCT(ArrayFormula({1; -1; 0}-E4);ArrayFormula({1; -1; 0}-E4);{B4;C4;D4}) / (sum(B4:D4)-1)`.

Comment: Also the POW function returns just one number. Mentioning this just for your info. I can't even use `B4:D4` inside the ArrayFormula as a parameter. I have to specify the cells like `{B4;C4;D4}`. Really must have something to do with internationalization.